# Total salary and commission by RELATIONAL SET OPERATOR

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Employee (emp_no, emp_fname, emp_lname, emp_salary,emp_comm, job_title)

use RELATIONAL SET OPERATOR

-- Write a sql query that calculates the total salary for all employees

-- You need to add the salary and commission

-- Note that some employees don't get a commission (here commission is null)

-- You must need UNION

Please help me to find the answer.

Comment: You should explain a litle better what you want, show us a sample of what your data looks like, and what you want as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need `UNION` to do this, Try this one

```
select sum(ifnull(emp_salary,0)+ifnull(emp_comm,0)) As Total
from yourtable
```

If you need `UNION` answer try this

```
SELECT SUM(salary) 
from
(
select sum(emp_salary) As salary
from yourtable
WHERE emp_salary IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
select sum(emp_comm) 
from yourtable
WHERE emp_comm IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: It might be quicker for the UNION version to use `WHERE emp_salary IS NOT NULL` rather than the `ifnull` for both statements.. Since it's a fictitious table it probably doesn't make a difference, but it's worth a mention.

Comment: @JNevill - Agreed and updated